# ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre "taumaturgo" y "mago"?

Tags: significado, sinónimos, diferencias-entre-palabras

El [Diccionario de la lengua española](https://dle.rae.es/) de la Real Academia Española define

[Taumaturgo](https://dle.rae.es/taumaturgo?):

> Del gr. θαυματουργός *thaumatourgós*, de θαῦμα, -ατος *thaûma, -atos* 'maravilla', 'cosa asombrosa' y -εργος *-ergos* 'que hace'.
>
> 1. m. y f. **mago** (‖ persona que practica la magia).

[Mago](https://dle.rae.es/mago):

> Del lat. *magnus*, y este del gr. μάγος *mágos*.
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que practica la magia.

¿Existe alguna diferencia o matiz [entrambas](https://dle.rae.es/entrambas)?

Answer (score 1):

Primero, lo más obvio: *mago* (como toda su familia de palabras) es una palabra mucho más común que *taumaturgia*. La mayoría de los hablantes conocen desde muy jóvenes las palabras *mago, magia, mágico*; muchos hablantes no conocen, o conocen pero nunca usan, las palabras *taumaturgo, -urgia, -úrgico*.

De aquí se desprende secundariamente que *mago* es una palabra que puede utilizarse para muchos tipos de personas, desde un mago "de verdad" (en la ficción, hasta donde sabemos; un mago del tipo de Gandalf o el de Harry Potter) hasta un ilusionista o un mero prestidigitador. Se usa *mago* en sentido figurado y ligero muchas veces (por ejemplo, se dice de alguien hábil en matemáticas que es "un mago para/con las cifras"). Por el contrario, *taumaturgo* es una palabra mucho más culta y transmite una seriedad que hace imposible utilizarla con tanta liviandad.

*Mago* es una persona que practica la magia, y la magia se asocia hoy en día a "trucos", o bien a una imagen tradicional que involucra hechizos, brebajes, pases con una varita, etc. *Taumaturgo* puede aplicarse, por el contrario, a alguien que no es un profesional o adepto de la magia, sino que simplemente tiene el [poder de hacer prodigios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taumaturgia) por algún don especial, como un santo.

De tiempos en que "magia" era considerada sinónimo de "brujería" viene una distinción entre la magia y la taumaturgia, incluyéndose en la última, por ejemplo, a la supuesta [curación de enfermos por intercesión de un rey o príncipe](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=4070460).

Y ya que hablábamos de El Señor de los Anillos, hay una escena que me parece importante en la distinción entre magia y taumaturgia en nuestra cultura, aunque esta última palabra no se utilice expresamente. En la visión católica de J. R. R. Tolkien era importante hacer una distinción entre la magia oscura, pagana, y los poderes en apariencia sobrenaturales de algunos personajes. En Lothlórien, la reina de los elfos, Galadriel, le pregunta a Sam si desea mirar en su Espejo, que puede mostrarle escenas de cosas que ocurrieron o que ocurrirán. Y le advierte:

> “Pues esto es lo que tu gente llama magia, aunque no entiendo claramente qué quieren decir, y **parece que usaran la misma palabra para hablar de los engaños del enemigo**. Pero ésta, si quieres, es la magia de Galadriel...”

Para mí es claro que Galadriel quiere explicarle con sencillez a Sam lo que tiene enfrente, pero también distinguir entre el poder de realizar prodigios (en último término concedido por Dios/Eru Ilúvatar, y que no involucra "trucos") y los poderes malignos de Sauron y sus criaturas, que se reducen a someter o engañar.